# Achartengine moving the legend independently

Tags: android, achartengine

I have an application using Achartengine and I am trying to move the legend independently. Every time I try to move it, it has some side effect.
Here is an image of the application:
[Image of my application where the legend overlaps the x axis labels but still shows]
[IMG]http://i42.tinypic.com/2jd2y6g.png[/IMG]
http://i42.tinypic.com/2jd2y6g.png

Here is an image of the application when I apply some solutions that I found here on stackoverflow:
[Image of my application where the legend has disappeared under the bottom of the screen]
[IMG]http://i44.tinypic.com/16bipmp.png[/IMG]
http://i44.tinypic.com/16bipmp.png

The thing I tried is to set the legend height with this method mRenderer.setLegendHeight(20);

The only thing I want to do is to move the legend down a few pixels so that it will not overlap the x axis labels or the x axis label name.
Moving the legend all the way to the top would be even better.
BTW I am also using mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30,0, 20 }); to set the margins and I have tried different combinations.
Any suggestions?

I can't post images yet.

Comment: Hard to guess without the images.

Comment: I uploaded the images to TinyPic and added the links. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a higher bottom margin, the third value in the array:

```
renderer.setMargins(new int[] { top, left, bottom, right });
```

You can also try the legend fit:

```
renderer.setFitLegend(true);
```

Comment: Okay. I managed to get it the way I wanted to.
A combination of Dans answer with mRenderer.setLegendHeight(45); and the bottom margin to 35 did it for me.

Comment: Seems so arbitrary the way those functions work because when you combine them and change a value it does something that you did not expect.
Maybe a short description of what each does with a picture to illustrate would be nice.
But I accept your answer as the correct one, Dan. Thanks.